# SQL case statement with aggregate value

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, case

I’m trying to transpose columns to rows using SQL case statement.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN a.known = true THEN ‘value1’
         WHEN a.known = true AND b.known = true THEN ‘value2’
         WHEN a.known = true AND b.known = false THEN ‘value3’
         WHEN a.known = true AND b.known = false AND b.aca=true THEN ‘value4’
    END AS ‘Column1’,
    COUNT(distinct a.abc) AS ‘Column2’
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
GROUP BY Column1
```

What I would like to see would be Column1 with value1, value2... and Column2 with their total.

Comment: unfortunately there's no native pivoting function in mysql. You may want to look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. All as formatted text, not images. And take a look at [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.known = true THEN a.abc END) as value1
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.known = true AND b.known = true THEN a.abc END) as value2,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.known = true AND b.known = false THEN a.abc END) as value3,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.known = true AND b.known = false AND b.aca=true THEN a.abc END) as value4
FROM a JOIN
     b
     ON a.id = b.id;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it is important that we understand what a group by is typically used for.

A COUNT() is an aggregate function that requires a GROUP BY.

Think of it this way Lets count how many "Steves" are in the a database.

We would have something like this:

```
`SELECT Name, COUNT(Name) AS Name FROM Customers`

This will error because we have no GROUP BY they dont know how to organize the data. So it should be
`SELECT Name, COUNT(Name) AS Name FROM Customers GROUP BY Name"`

In your case:
select

case when a.known=true then ‘value1’

when a.known=true and b.known=true then ‘value2’

when a.known=true and b.known=false then ‘value3’

when a.known=true and b.known=false and b.aca=true then ‘value4’

end as ‘Column1’,

count(distinct a.abc) as ‘Column2’

from a Join b on a.id=b.id

group by column1
```

`

Comment: OP is asking for a pivot function. It's ok to `count(distinct a.abc)` as long as it's already grouped by something even on a different key. the `count` will count non-null values